# Converting a column value when filtering in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In a csv file which I read using pandas, there's a column of type bool but in the string format which is 'F' or 'T'. How can I convert it to the real Bool when filtering? No need to change in the source file, only when filtering:

```
# how it is now
if something:
  df1 = df1[df1['str_bool_column'] == 'F']

# how I want
if something:
  df1 = df1[df1['str_bool_column'] == False]
```

I probably should use `apply`, but how exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert that column to a column of `True/False` values after reading it from the csv. One method to do that would be to use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) , to map `'F'` to `False` and `'T'` to `True`. Example -

```
df1['str_bool_column'] = df1['str_bool_column'].map({'F':False,'T':True})
```

Demo -

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'F'],[2,'T'],[3,'F'],[4,'T']],columns=['A','B'])

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   A  B
0  1  F
1  2  T
2  3  F
3  4  T

In [11]: df['B'] = df['B'].map({'F':False,'T':True})

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A      B
0  1  False
1  2   True
2  3  False
3  4   True
```